# Unable to pass multiple parameters in onclick php

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to pass multiple parameters in an `onclick` with variables, although coming up with an error of

> - Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list.

The error is on this line

```
echo'<a onclick="changebill('.$myrow['address_ID'].', '.$myrow['address_1'].', '.$myrow['address_2'].');"> ';
```

Comment: What do you see when you look at it in View Source in the browser?

Comment: If these values are strings, you need to put quotes around them in the Javascript.

Comment: Is this part of an `echo` statement? Show more of the PHP code so we can see how it's being used.

Comment: ah sorry for the delayed response guys, it is indeed being echoed

Comment: updated the answer see if it fixes the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to the following if the anchor is inside the `echo` statement

```
echo  '<a onclick="changebill(\''.$myrow['address_ID'].'\', \''.$myrow['address_1'].'\', \''.$myrow['address_2'].'\');"> ';
```

You have to add the quotes around the parameters as the text you are sending might contain spaces and break. Your code will output it like below

```
<a onclick="changebill(1, my house address, my street number);">
```

whereas it should be like

```
<a onclick="changebill('1', 'my house address', 'my street number');">
```

Comment: His style is correct it this is part of a string being echoed.

Comment: You probably shouldn't assume people have PHP short tags enabled.

Comment: if that whole anchor is inside the php echo statement then yes @Barmar

Comment: sorry i've updated my question the onlcick is being echoed

Answer (score 0):

Try using double quotes. Use \" for every time you have to use double quotes anywhere.

```
echo "<a onclick=\"changebill( " . $myrow['address_ID'] . " , " . $myrow['address_1'] . " , " . $myrow['address_2']  . ") \">";
```

Comment: Look at the code in the question, he's using single quotes around the string. So it's not necessary to escape double quotes inside it.

Comment: I used the double quotes instead. Personal preference. They make the code look simpler.

Comment: Your output is identical to what's in the question.